# What is the best way to Manage meeting attendees in custom list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, lookup-column

I am trying to manage a custom list for a large meeting in SharePoint 2013 .

I already have a contact list with all information, *this will be my basic invitation list*.

The person who call for invitation should use this list's info, but I'm wondering which option is better:

1. I can add a choice column so he can fill it while calling *(Accept/Decline/Tentative)* but **the column was added to the basic contact list.**
2. I can make another list with a `lookup` column to basic information list and  another `choice` column to fill.

**Which option is better for manage a custom list in SharePoint 2013 based on the points described above?**

Comment: I edited your question, feel free for edit your question and add more information that can use the SharePoint Stack Exchange community.

Comment: Thanks for editing! I saw my mistakes. For next time I will try to use your experiences so I will write better sentences to show the exact meaning.